# tensorflow where to store the restored checkpoints

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
 _ = importer.import_graph_def(input_graph_def, name='')

with session.Session() as sess:
    if input_saver_def:
      saver = saver_lib.Saver(saver_def=input_saver_def)
      saver.restore(sess, input_checkpoint)
output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        sess,
        input_graph_def,
        output_node_names.split(','),
        variable_names_blacklist=variable_names_blacklist)
```

In the code above, the importer is used to import the graphDef to the current default graph, and the saver loads the previously trained values. The question is where these trained values are stored? In the session, in the input_graph_def, in the current graph structure(tf.get_default_graph()) or in the saver?

I check the code of method `convert_variables_to_constants`. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/235192d47cfb375c0cc93c1deefb9e440715bf35/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_util_impl.py

It uses sess.run(variable name) to fetch loaded values. Where does this `sess.run` fetch values from?

Answer (score 0):

When we define the saver we should pass the notes to it(it is the global variables by default).

```
In [2]: import tensorflow as tf
In [3]: a = tf.get_variable("a", [])
In [4]: b = tf.get_variable("b", [])
In [5]: saver_a = tf.train.Saver({"my_a_in_ckpt": a}) # here "my_a_in_ckpt" can be any apt name you like, it is the variable name stored only in the checkpoint (1)
In [6]: init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
In [7]: sess = tf.Session()
In [8]: sess.run(init)
In [9]: sess.run(a)
Out[9]: 0.43891537
In [10]: sess.run(b)
Out[10]: 1.5962805
In [11]: saver_a.save(sess, "./temp_model")
```

Here we first initialize all variables and save a to "./temp_model". To restore the variable:

```
In [2]: import tensorflow as tf
In [3]: a = tf.get_variable("a", []) 
In [5]: saver_a = tf.train.Saver({"my_a_in_ckpt": a})  # here "my_a_in_ckpt" should match that as you defined in step (1)
In [7]: sess = tf.Session()
In [9]: saver_a.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("./temp_model"))
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./temp_model/temp
In [10]: sess.run(a)
Out[10]: 0.43891537
In [11]: sess.run(b)
Out[11]: 1.5962805
```

And we can save a and b into different places:

```
In [12]: saver_b = tf.train.Saver({"b": b})
In [13]: saver_b.save(sess, "./temp_model_b/temp")
Out[13]: './temp_model_b/temp'
```

and restore them to a graph:

```
In [3]: a = tf.get_variable("a", [])
In [4]: b = tf.get_variable("b", [])
In [5]: saver_b = tf.train.Saver({"b": b})
In [6]: saver_a = tf.train.Saver({"my_a_in_ckpt": a})
In [7]: saver_a.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("./temp_model"))                              
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./temp_model/temp
In [8]: saver_b.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("./temp_model_b"))
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./temp_model_b/temp
In [9]: sess.run(a)
Out[9]: 0.43891537
In [10]: sess.run(b)
Out[10]: 1.5962805
```